# Big long numerics dividing with round

Tags: java, android

I have problem with java then i want to divade big long type numerics for example if i divide 165600139 / 86400000 = 1.9, but my method return 1 without rounding :/

```
public static long calcDaysBefore(Date date) {
    int MILISECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long days = 0;
    if (date != null) {
        long current = getCurrentDate().getTime() - date.getTime();
        days = current / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY;
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: You might also be interested in the [`DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class; seems like you might be reinventing the wheel. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rounding down and is similar to doing

```
days = Math.floor((double) current / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY);
```

If you want to round half up you can write

```
days = (current + MILISECONDS_IN_DAY/2) / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY;
```

Using floating point you could use the following which is much slower.

```
days = Math.round((double) current / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY);
```

if you want to round up you can do

```
days = (current + MILISECONDS_IN_DAY-1) / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY;
```

or

```
days = Math.ceil((double) current / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY);
```

btw milli-seconds has two l's

Answer (score 1):

actually the result is rounded, there are several rounding modes, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html, in your case you are getting the number of full days. For rounding to the closest long we can use

```
long days = Math.round(current / 8640000.0);
```

Comment: This is fine if `days = 2` ;)

Answer (score 0):

cast to double.

```
days = (double)current / (double)MILISECONDS_IN_DAY;
```